# WPF: modifying property of elements in common control template

Tags: .net, wpf, controltemplate

I have made a `ControlTemplate` for buttons in `Resources` as below:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="buttonCtrlTemp" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <DockPanel x:Name="dock">
                        <Image x:Name="btnImg" Height="16" Width="16" DockPanel.Dock="Left"/>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Button.Content}"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="dock" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource AppBlue}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

I am referencing this from the button as

`<Button Content="Login" Template="{StaticResource buttonCtrlTemp}"/>`

However, I want to have different image for different buttons and hence will need some way to set the source of the `Image` element in the control template from the button. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Tag` in this case. Example:

In `Template`:

```
<Image x:Name="btnImg" Source="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Height="16" Width="16" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
```

Using:

```
<!-- In Resources -->
<BitmapImage x:Key="MyFind" UriSource="/BlackFind.jpg" />

<Button Name="FindTestButton" Tag="{StaticResource MyFind}" Template="{StaticResource buttonCtrlTemp}" ... />
```

In template is better to use `ContentPresenter` instead `TextBlock`. Because this control is responsible for displaying the *contents* of the control, which is his only goal. Accordingly, in first, it is smaller than the "weigh" (nearly all controls have your `ContentPresenter`), and secondly the content may be a universal type. Full example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="MyFind" UriSource="/BlackFind.jpg" />
    <BitmapImage x:Key="MyAttach" UriSource="/attachment.png" />

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="buttonCtrlTemp" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <DockPanel x:Name="dock" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
            <Image x:Name="btnImg" Source="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Height="16" Width="16" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
        </DockPanel>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="dock" Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button Name="FindTestButton" Width="100" Tag="{StaticResource MyFind}" Background="Gainsboro" Content="FindButton" Height="30" Template="{StaticResource buttonCtrlTemp}" />
    <Button Name="AttachTestButton" Width="100" Tag="{StaticResource MyAttach}" Background="Gainsboro" Content="AttachButton" Height="30" Template="{StaticResource buttonCtrlTemp}" Margin="0,80,0,0" />
</Grid>
```

`Output`

[image]